# Can not uninstall app after Test Installation Flow

Tags: google-apps-marketplace

After configuring the app (enabled installation for single user) I've tried the Test Installation Flow with my non-gsuite account:

[image]

The flow went as expected. But now, I can not test the flow again, because the app seems to be installed, and I'm taken directly to my app. I went to security settings of my account and revoked all permissions for the app, but the flow still not wokring and the app still appears in my GMails apps:

[image]

**How do I remove the test app from my account completely? How can I test the installation flow again?**

Answer (score 0):

Follow this [Remove a G Suite service](https://support.google.com/a/answer/45691?hl=en) guide:

> **Remove a service for everyone**
>   1. Sign in to your Google Admin console. Sign in using an administrator account, not your current account
>   reyanthonyrenacia@gmail.com
>
> 2. From the Home page, click Apps.
> 3. Click the type of service you want to remove (G Suite or Marketplace apps).
> 4. Click the service you want to remove.
> 5. Scroll to the bottom and click the Uninstall link. For some services you might need to go to a separate sub-page, for example, by
>      clicking General Settings or Advanced Settings.
>
> The service is removed from the list of services in the Admin console.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Didn't make myself clear I think. I'm testing the flow on a personal gmail account. There's no _admin_ account that manages my account. They're both the same gmail account. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To uninstall an app go to https://gsuite.google.com/marketplace/myapps, find the app, click on the vertical dots and select Remove.